# Why is my code output incorrect (i only want to receive integers as key)?

Tags: c, if-statement, output, command-line-arguments, cs50

Why is my code output incorrect (i only want to receive integers as key)?

In the following code what I'm trying to say to the computer is to **'only accept int's as key, otherwise reject the key'**.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])                           //command line argument
{

  for ( int i = 0; i< strlen(argv[1]); i++)
  {
  if (argc != 2)                                            //correct argument count
  {
    printf ("usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
  }
  else if(isdigit(argv[1][i]))
  {
     printf("success\n");
  }
  else if(isalpha(argv[1][i]))
  {
    printf ("usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

However, when I tried different inputs to test the accuracy of my code this is what happened:

```
~/caesar/ $ ./caesar 4r       //<--mix of outputs.i don't want 'success' here bc input has a letter
success
usage: ./caesar key
~/caesar/ $ ./caesar g5       //correct output
usage: ./caesar key
~/caesar/ $ ./caesar r        //correct output
usage: ./caesar key
```

As you can see, when I **input a letter *and then* an int**, it works fine, but when I **do the opposite (int and then letter), it would give me a mix of outputs**, both rejecting and accepting the output.

Answer (score 0):

your problem comes because while the first characters are digit you print 'success' for each, you must wait you checked all the characters to decide you success

Note also to do

> ```
> if (argc != 2)                                            //correct argument count
> {
>   printf ("usage: ./caesar key\n");
>   return 1;
> }
> ```

inside the loop is useless, move that before the loop

to do `strlen(argv[1])` each turn is expensive for nothing

you want something like that :

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])                           //command line argument
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf ("usage: %s key\n", *argv);
    return 1;
  }

  for (int i = 0; argv[1][i] != 0; i++)
  {
    if(!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
    {
      printf ("usage: %s key\n", *argv); // better to say the key is not an integer
      return 1;
    }
  }  

  puts("success");
  return 0;
}
```

I suppose a negative integer is refused and there is no limit to the size of the accepted integer (an `int` may not be enough because of overflow)

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Dstring="char*" -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 123
success
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1a
usage: ./a.out key
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out a1
usage: ./a.out key
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out ""
success
```

What must be done if the argument is empty ? currently it is a success but probably it must not be, so a way is to replace

```
 if (argc != 2)
```

by

```
 if ((argc != 2) || !argv[1][0])
```